# How to solve code analysis warning CA1506 : "Avoid excessive class coupling"

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.0, .net-4.5, code-analysis

I am facing CA1506 code analysis warning for following code

```
private void ShowProductStatistics(object obj)
    {
        this.currentProduct = obj as Products;
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            var topOrderQuery = (from orderDetail in new XPQuery<OrderDetails>(new Session())
                                 where
                                     orderDetail.ProductID.ProductID == currentProduct.ProductID
                                 orderby
                                     (orderDetail.UnitPrice * orderDetail.Quantity) descending
                                 select new TopOrder
                                 {
                                     OrderId = orderDetail.OrderID.OrderID,
                                     TotalSales = orderDetail.UnitPrice * orderDetail.Quantity
                                 }).ToList().Take(10);

            DispatcherExt.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => { this.TopProduct = topOrderQuery; }));

            var orderPerYearQuery = (from order in new XPQuery<OrderDetails>(new Session())
                                     where order.ProductID.ProductID == currentProduct.ProductID
                                     group order by new { order.OrderID.OrderDate.Year }
                                         into g
                                         select new OrderPYear
                                         {
                                             TotalOrder = g.Count(),
                                             OrderYear = g.Key.Year
                                         }).ToList();
            DispatcherExt.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => { this.OrderPerYear = orderPerYearQuery; }));

            var salesPerYearQuery = (from order in new XPQuery<OrderDetails>(new Session())
                                     where order.ProductID.ProductID == currentProduct.ProductID
                                     group order by new { order.OrderID.OrderDate.Year }
                                         into g
                                         select new SalesPYear
                                         {
                                             Sales = g.Sum(p => p.UnitPrice * p.Quantity),
                                             Year = g.Key.Year
                                         }).ToList();
            DispatcherExt.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => { this.SalesPerYear = salesPerYearQuery; }));
        });
    }
```

I tried to solve this warning by following suggestions given in the msdn but not succeeded.
Can anybody help me to solve this warning ??

Thanks & regards,
Rudresh

Comment: There are a bunch of classes that you can't see, generated by the Linq query comprehensions.  The code analyzer sees them but is noddy about it, just suppress the warning.

Comment: Hello Hans,Thanks for your suggestion but I got the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the code as follows.

```
this.currentProduct = obj as Products;
        List<OrderDetails> orderDetailLIst = new XPQuery<OrderDetails>(new Session()).ToList();
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            var topOrderQuery = (from orderDetail in orderDetailLIst
                                 where
                                     orderDetail.ProductID.ProductID == currentProduct.ProductID
                                 orderby
                                     (orderDetail.UnitPrice * orderDetail.Quantity) descending
                                 select new TopOrder
                                 {
                                     OrderId = orderDetail.OrderID.OrderID,
                                     TotalSales = orderDetail.UnitPrice * orderDetail.Quantity
                                 }).ToList().Take(10);

            DispatcherExt.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => { this.TopProduct = topOrderQuery; }));

            var orderPerYearQuery = (from order in orderDetailLIst
                                     where order.ProductID.ProductID == currentProduct.ProductID
                                     group order by new { order.OrderID.OrderDate.Year }
                                         into g
                                         select new OrderPYear
                                         {
                                             TotalOrder = g.Count(),
                                             OrderYear = g.Key.Year
                                         }).ToList();
            DispatcherExt.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => { this.OrderPerYear = orderPerYearQuery; }));

            var salesPerYearQuery = (from order in orderDetailLIst
                                     where order.ProductID.ProductID == currentProduct.ProductID
                                     group order by new { order.OrderID.OrderDate.Year }
                                         into g
                                         select new SalesPYear
                                         {
                                             Sales = g.Sum(p => p.UnitPrice * p.Quantity),
                                             Year = g.Key.Year
                                         }).ToList();
            DispatcherExt.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => { this.SalesPerYear = salesPerYearQuery; }));
        });
```

The cause of warning was "from orderDetail in new XPQuery(new Session())" statement which I was using 3 times therefore it was giving warning. I tried to reduce coupling.

Comment: Although you've found your own solution and want to share it, you'd better explain what is causing it and describe why it's causing it and how you came up with your solution.

Comment: The cause of warning was "from orderDetail in new XPQuery<OrderDetails>(new Session())" statement which I was using 3 times therefore it was giving warning. I tried to reduce coupling.